# Ember template renders function as string

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm new to ember and got a problem with a template.

**My route**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model: function(params) {

    var pageNum   = params.page || 1,
        pageRows  = 8;

    return this.store.find('account', {
      page: pageNum,
      rows: pageRows
    });
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
    controller.set('greeting', 'Hello World');
  }
});
```

**My Controller**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  contentLength: function() {
    // console.log(this);
    // console.log('length: ' + this.get('content').length);
    // return this.get('content').length;
    return 'Test string';
  },

  actions: {}
});
```

**Template**

```
{{ greeting }}
{{ contentLength }}
```

The {{ greeting }} gets rendered correctly. But {{ contentLength }} gets rendered out as a string function..

```
Hello World function () { // console.log(this); // console.log('length: ' + this.get('content').length); // return this.get('content').length; return 'Test string'; }
```

Anyone who can help me solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `.property()` at the end of the `contentLength` function in order to display it in a template:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  contentLength: function() {
    // console.log(this);
    // console.log('length: ' + this.get('content').length);
    // return this.get('content').length;
    return 'Test string';
  }.property(),

  actions: {}
});
```

If you want the property to update whenever another property of your controller changes simply add it as a "parameter" of your property like this `.property("thepropertytoobserve")` and the length property of an arrayController is already aviable as `{{length}}` in the template.

Have a look at the [doc](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/) for more details on computerd properties.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain to me why this behaviour is in place? It seems counter-intuitive to me. But it's probably just my limited understanding of Ember.

Comment: It's to make the distinction between computed properties and Ember Object functions. The computed properties add some cache for optimization. The first time the property is rendered the function is executed, the second time the information is just returned from cache unless one of the observed value changes. I would advice you to check the doc on computed property and also on observers in ember doc that's some of the powerful mechanisms in ember

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `{{ length }}` in your template as ArrayControllers already have that property.

The reason your `contentLength` function is not doing what you want is because it is not a computed property. You need to either use `Ember.computed(function() { ..})` or  append `.property(...)` to your `contentLength` function.

Eg:

```
contentLength: function() {
  return this.get('content.length');
}.property('content.length')
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Im a little frustrated that you can't just add custom stuff to display in a template. But maybe im just defining it in the wrong place? Anyway, adding .property('modelName') seemed to do the trick.